# PHP rounding the Exponent to number

Tags: php

Can any one explain how to round the exponent number to decimal i.e `1.5636078182346E+48` to `2` and `-1.6401906104806E+50` to `2`.

sample code:-

```
$string = "1.5636078182346E+48";
echo $float  = (float) $string;
```

No any conversion. while such code

```
$string = "7.2769482308e+01";
$float  = (float) $string;
```

is working . why ? What is the wrong ?

Comment: `intval`/`floatval` might do what you're looking for.

Comment: Because that +48 is too big I think. Change that to 13, and it will works. Of course, that is not the same number, I know. See the warning section here. There are something about the limitation: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for `round()` you can use it like this:

```
$float  = (float) "1.5636078182346e+48";
echo round($float, -48);

echo "<br>";

$float = (float) "-1.6401906104806E+50"; 
echo round($float, -50);

//output:
//2.0E+48
//-2.0E+50
```

The first parameter is the float to be rounded, second parameter is the number of numbers after decimal point (negative means it will round larger numbers, i.e. 1234 becomes 1200 if you use -2)

Documentation here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

And your second example prints the number without the e+xx because it is small enough number, so it will not be automatically converted to the exponent form.